# Update database in one frame and show updated values in another

Tags: java, arrays, database, swing

I have created a banking system where the user can deposit only (for now). My program uses the MS Access database. I've loaded the database; everything is working well enough. Except, when the user makes a deposit, while the database is being updated at the click of the "deposit" button, the user has to log out and log back in to see the updated balance (this is in another frame called "Account Details).

Is there a way to refresh the database at the click of the button so it refreshes throughout the entire program? I've also been looking at the arrays. Can I store the database in the array and call it back in the Account Details window? If so, how can I do this?

LoadData window where I am loading the database

```
public static Account accounts[] = new Account[2];
public static Customer people[] = new Customer[2];
public static CreditCard credit[] = new CreditCard[2];
public static Mortgage mortgage[] = new Mortgage[2];
public static Transaction trans[] = new Transaction[100];

LoadData()
{
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        //Connect to the database
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:///Volumes/GREEN GRASS/JSProject/prjTIMS_JS/Bank11.mdb");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully.");

        //Retrieve data from Salesperson table
        String sqlAccount = "SELECT * FROM tblAccount";
        ResultSet rsAccount = st.executeQuery(sqlAccount);

        //Loop through the results to load the data into the Salesperson array
        while (rsAccount.next())
        {


            //Retrieve by column name
            int cid = rsAccount.getInt("custID");
            int can = rsAccount.getInt("checkingAcctNum");
            int san = rsAccount.getInt("savingsAcctNum");
            int soan = rsAccount.getInt("soarAcctNum");
            String ccan = rsAccount.getString("creditCardAcctNum");
            int man = rsAccount.getInt("mortgageAcctNum");
            int clan = rsAccount.getInt("carLoanAcctNum");
            double cab = rsAccount.getDouble("checkingAcctBal");
            double sab = rsAccount.getDouble("savingsAcctBal");
            double soab = rsAccount.getDouble("soarAcctBal");

            //Load record into the Salesperson array
            accounts[i] = new Account(cid,can,san,soan,ccan,man,clan,cab,sab,soab);
            i++;
        }

        rsAccount.close();
        System.out.println("Loaded tblAccount table.");

        //Retrieve data from the Customer table
        String sqlCustomer = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomer";
        ResultSet rsCustomer = st.executeQuery(sqlCustomer);
        i = 0;

        //Loop through the results to load the data into the Customer array
        while (rsCustomer.next()) 
        {   
            //Retrieve by column name
            int cid = rsCustomer.getInt("custID");
            String ti = rsCustomer.getString("title");
            String fn = rsCustomer.getString("fName");
            String ln = rsCustomer.getString("lName");
            String un = rsCustomer.getString("username");
            String pw = rsCustomer.getString("password");
            int sn = rsCustomer.getInt("SSN");
            String uid = rsCustomer.getString("uniqueID");
            String sk = rsCustomer.getString("sightkey");
            int hn = rsCustomer.getInt("houseNum");
            String stn = rsCustomer.getString("streetName");
            String ci = rsCustomer.getString("city");
            String sta = rsCustomer.getString("state");
            int zc = rsCustomer.getInt("zipcode");
            String pn = rsCustomer.getString("phoneNum");
            String em = rsCustomer.getString("email");

            //Load record into the Customer array
            people[i] = new Customer(cid,ti,fn,ln,un,pw,sn,uid,sk,hn,stn,ci,sta,zc,pn,em);
            i++;
        }


        rsCustomer.close();
        System.out.println("Loaded tblCustomer table.");

        //Retrieve data from the Car table
        String sqlCreditCard = "SELECT * FROM tblCreditCard";
        ResultSet rsCreditCard = st.executeQuery(sqlCreditCard);
        i = 0;

        //Loop through the results to load the data into the Customer array     
        while (rsCreditCard.next()) 
        {
            //Retrieve by column name
            int cid = rsCreditCard.getInt("custID");
            String ld = rsCreditCard.getString("loanDate");
            float air = rsCreditCard.getFloat("annualInterestRate");
            double la = rsCreditCard.getDouble("loanAmount");
            double bal = rsCreditCard.getDouble("balance");
            int lt = rsCreditCard.getInt("loanTerm");
            double cmp = rsCreditCard.getDouble("ccMonthlyPayment");

            //Load record into the Car array
            credit[i] = new CreditCard(cid,ld,air,la,bal,lt,cmp);
            i++;
        }


            //Close the result sets and the connection
            rsCreditCard.close();

            //Retrieve data from the Car table
            String sqlMortgage = "SELECT * FROM tblMortgage";
            ResultSet rsMortgage = st.executeQuery(sqlMortgage);
            i = 0;

            //Loop through the results to load the data into the Customer array     
            while (rsMortgage.next()) 
        {
            //Retrieve by column name
            int cid = rsMortgage.getInt("custID");
            String mld = rsMortgage.getString("mloanDate");
            float hv = rsMortgage.getFloat("homeValue");
            double mla = rsMortgage.getDouble("mortLoanAmount");
            double mair = rsMortgage.getDouble("mortAnnualInterestRate");
            int mlt = rsMortgage.getInt("mortLoanTerm");
            double mmp = rsMortgage.getDouble("mortMonthlyPayment");
            double tp = rsMortgage.getDouble("totalPayments");

            //Load record into the Car array
            mortgage[i] = new Mortgage(cid,mld,hv,mla,mair,mlt,mmp,tp);
            i++;
        }
            //Close the result sets and the connection
            rsMortgage.close();
            System.out.println("Loaded tblMortgage table.");

            //Retrieve data from the Car table
            String sqlTransaction = "SELECT * FROM tblTransaction";
            ResultSet rsTransaction = st.executeQuery(sqlTransaction);
            i = 0;

            //Loop through the results to load the data into the Customer array     
            while (rsTransaction.next()) 
            {
                //Retrieve by column name
                int tc = rsTransaction.getInt("transCount");
                int cid = rsTransaction.getInt("custID");
                int tn = rsTransaction.getInt("transNum");
                String tt = rsTransaction.getString("transType");
                String td = rsTransaction.getString("transDate");

                //Load record into the Car array
                trans[i] = new Transaction(tc,cid,tn,tt,td);
                i++;
            }

                //Close the result sets and the connection
                rsTransaction.close();
                System.out.println("Loaded tblTransactions table.");
            conn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("can't get" +e);
    }
}
```

ACCOUNT DETAILS window (I know that something has to be done in this window to reflect the updated the balance that was made in the Deposit window, just not sure how)

```
public AccountDetailsWindow(int customerindex) throws IOException{


    //THIS SHOWS THE BALANCES AND ACCOUNT NUMBERS
    //I KNOW I NEED TO INSERT SOMETHING HERE TO REFLECT THE NEW BALANCE CHANGES, IF ANY
    JLabel lblCbal = new JLabel("$"+LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getCheckingAcctBal());
    lblCbal.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblSbal = new JLabel("$"+LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getSavingsAcctBal());
    lblSbal.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblSobal = new JLabel("$"+LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getSoarAcctBal());
    lblSobal.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblCCbal = new JLabel("$"+LoadData.credit[customerindex].getBalance());
    lblCCbal.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblMbal = new JLabel("$"+LoadData.mortgage[customerindex].getTotalPayments());
    lblMbal.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblCacct = new JLabel("#"+LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getCheckingAcctNum());
    lblCacct.setForeground(new Color(245, 135, 79));
    lblCacct.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblSacct = new JLabel("#"+LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getSavingsAcctNum());
    lblSacct.setForeground(new Color(245, 135, 79));
    lblSacct.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblSoacct = new JLabel("#"+LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getSoarAcctNum());
    lblSoacct.setForeground(new Color(245, 135, 79));
    lblSoacct.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblCCacct = new JLabel("#"+LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getCreditCardAcctNum());
    lblCCacct.setForeground(new Color(245, 135, 79));
    lblCCacct.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    JLabel lblMacct = new JLabel("#"+LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getMortgageAcctNum());
    lblMacct.setForeground(new Color(245, 135, 79));
    lblMacct.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
```

DEPOSIT window which contains the methods for updating the balances as deposits are made.

```
    public static int i = 0;

    double DTSoar, DTChecking, DTSavings, newCB, newSB, newSoB;
    double checkAmount;

    int transNum = 4;
    String transType = "Deposit";

    // Get current date time
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(); 
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime()); 

DepositCheckWindow(int customerindex) throws IOException, ParseException{


    //Create Make Deposit button
    JButton depositButton = new JButton ("Make Deposit"); 
    depositButton.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12));
    depositButton.setOpaque(false);
    depositButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 22));
    depositButton.setForeground(new Color(251, 125, 24));

    BufferedImage buttonIcon6 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/depositbtn.png"));
    depositButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon6));
    depositButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    depositButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    depositButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);

    // Add Listener to Make Deposit button
    depositButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // Retrieve the value from the text field
        checkAmount = (Double) txtAmt.getValue();

        //checkAmount = Double.parseDouble(txtAmt.getText());


        //DEPOSIT TO CHECKING ACCOUNT
        if (toList.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Checking Account")){
            DTChecking += checkAmount;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have successfully deposited " + checkAmount+" to your Checking Account.");          
            }

        //DEPOSIT TO SAVINGS ACCOUNT
        else if (toList.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Savings Account")){
            DTSavings += checkAmount;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have successfully deposited $" + checkAmount+" to your Savings Account.");
            }

        //DEPOSIT TO SOAR ACCOUNT
         else if (toList.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Soar Account")){
            DTSoar += checkAmount;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have successfully deposited $" + checkAmount+" to your Soar Account.");
            }

        try {
            calculateBalances(customerindex);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        txtAmt.setText("");
    }});



//Calculate new account balances
void calculateBalances(int customerindex) throws IOException
{ 
    //Calculate newCB - new Savings Account Balance
    newCB = LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getCheckingAcctBal() + DTChecking;

    //Calculate newSB - new Savings Account Balance
    newSB = LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getSavingsAcctBal() + DTSavings;

    //Calculate new SoB - new Soar Account Balance
    newSoB = LoadData.accounts[customerindex].getSoarAcctBal() + DTSoar;

    //Call methods
    depositFunds(customerindex);
    saveTransaction();  
}

//Update account balances
boolean depositFunds(int customerindex){
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        //Connect to the database
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:///Volumes/GREEN GRASS/JSProject/prjTIMS_JS/Bank11.mdb");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully ...");

        String upProfile = "UPDATE tblAccount SET checkingAcctBal = '" +newCB+ "', savingsAcctBal = '" +newSB+ "', soarAcctBal = '" +newSoB+ "' WHERE custID = '" +LoadData.accounts[i].getCustID()+ "'";
        stmt.execute(upProfile);

        conn.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Accounts table updated successfully");
    }
    catch( Exception e ){
        System.out.println("Can't retrieve from database connection: "+e);
    }
    return true;
}

//Write to the transaction table
void saveTransaction(){
    try
    {
        int transCount = 0;
        //Connect to the database
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:///Volumes/GREEN GRASS/JSProject/prjTIMS_JS/Bank11.mdb");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully ...");

        String inTransaction = "insert into tblTransaction (transCount,"+ "custID,"+ "transNum," + "transType, "+ "transDate) "+ "values('"+transCount+"','"+ LoadData.accounts[i].getCustID()+"','"+transNum+"','"+transType+"','"+ts+"')"; 
        transCount++;

        stmt.execute(inTransaction);
        conn.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Transaction table values inserted successfully");
    }
    catch( Exception e ){
        System.out.println("Can't retrieve from database connection: "+e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Once you've update the database, and committed the transaction, you need to reload the values from the database...Oh, and I'd consider using a dialog instead of second frame, this way you can wait till the dialog is closed and determine what action to take based on the results of the dialog

Comment: @MadProgrammer That means that I use back the same code in the LoadData class in the saveTransaction method?

Comment: Without a runnable example, that would be my "guess"

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's not working. I made it into a method and called it after the saveTransaction method and it didn't work. So I made another method in the Account Details window and called it before the balances were loaded; that didn't work. Thanks for your previous suggestion. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.

Comment: @blackbishop You helped me in a previous question and it helped a lot. I was wondering if you can help here too. I've almost completed my assignment but I have an issue where I'm trying to update the database and show the updated values of the database in another frame. Can you help me? For some reason it won't show unless I log out and log back into the program. Thanks